# Different Casimirs and Casimirs of $E_6$

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, invariants

I am a bit confused by the notion of Casimirs (maybe it is related to terminology). In the simplest example of $su(2)$ with generators $L_i$, we get the Casimir operator  $$ L^2=\sum_i L_i^2$$

Especially this element takes different value when evaluating for different representation, which is $j(j+1)$ for spin-$j$ representation of $su(2)$. This can be easily generalized to other algebra, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element.

On the other hand, I find people are talking about another kind of Casimirs. In the simplest case of su(N), take any element $X$ in the Lie algebra and then consider
$$
S_k=\text{Tr} X^k, \qquad k=2, 3, \cdots N
$$
This type of $S_k$  elements are also called Casimirs as far as I can see from literature and only $N-1$ of them are independent. Especially one can take $X$ as an element in Cartan sub-algebra and expand $X=\sum_j m_j H_j$. Then $S_k$ can be represented as a symmetry function of these eigenvalues $m_j$.

I am wondering what are the exact relationship between these two types of Casimirs? I roughly can understand but I am curious about the exact treatment in math literature.

Actually my real question is for $E_6$, how can I write $S_k$ in terms of $m_j$, just like the $su(N)$ case?

Comment: The $\mathrm{Tr} X^k$ quantities are non-trivial whenever there are totally symmetric parts of $\mathrm{Tr} [T^{a_1} \dots T^{a_k}]$. These are the (quadratic, cubic, etc) Casimirs. The number of independent Casimirs is equal to the rank but their degrees don't always go $2,3,4, \dots$. I can't remember which ones exist for $E_6$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the number of Casimirs is just the rank. Do you known where  I can find the Casimirs for E_6 (not just their degree)? Any useful book? Thanks!